# What are hypothetical indexes?

Tags: sql-server, index

They seem to be created by tools like DTA.

For practical purposes they could be [deleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190172.aspx), ignored or chosen to be created, but until then, they have no direct influence on the database.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/anurag_sharma/archive/2008/04/15/hypothetical-indexes.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hypothetical indexes are not actually there and can be ignored.  They don't contain any data and can be safely deleted.